# Error on flutter pub run build_runner build

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am facing this issue when I run flutter pub run build_runner build. I have tried solutions like flutter clean, flutter pub-cache repair flutter pub get, etc. Dependencies like Mockito, HTTP, and build_runner are added on pubspec and flutter pub get ran successfully as well.

```
Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1600:40: Error: Getter not found: 'topLevelVariable'.
      return kinds.contains(TargetKind.topLevelVariable);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2024:23: Error: Getter not found: 'topLevelVariable'.
      case TargetKind.topLevelVariable:
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2024:23: Error: Type 'dynamic' of the case expression is not a subtype of type 'TargetKind' of this switch expression.
 - 'TargetKind' is from 'package:meta/meta_meta.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0/lib/meta_meta.dart').
      case TargetKind.topLevelVariable:
                      ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2001:13: Context: The switch expression is here.
    switch (this) {
            ^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 13):

adding the analyser https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer dependency 1.5.0 in the dev-dependencies of pubspec yaml worked for me

```
 dev_dependencies:
   analyzer: 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46136#issuecomment-848910733, you should be able to just run `flutter pub upgrade` without specifying any `analyzer` version, and it'll work!

Answer (score 3):

Try add these lines to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
   meta: 1.6.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't wanted to upgrade to latest version for the moment. This is a good solution for anyone who don't want to upgrade to latest versions for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

This will do the thing. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

dependency_overrides:
analyzer: '1.5.0'

Adding this pubspec.yaml file worked for me

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be an issue with newest verson of analyser. I was able to fix it by just downgrading the version from 1.6.0 to 1.5.0.

dev_dependencies:
analyzer: 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case build runner, I have upgraded build runner and few other dependency.

###### Build runner for generating part files

build_runner: ^2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Update dependencies to latest versions. It's works for me.

```
auto_route:
build_runner:
auto_route_generator:
```